# Java - Picking one ArrayList out of many different types

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm making a grid/tile based game. Each tile on the grid has a few attributes a x position, y position, and an ID. The ID changes based on what occupies the tile. Currently, there are two different types of buildings that can occupy a tile, a command center, or a turret. If I wanted to delete a building, I would need to remove it from it's ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<CommandCenter> commandCenters = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Turret> turrets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Structure IDs:

```
Command Center : 1
Turret : 2
...
```

How can I pick which ArrayList to remove from, given the ID? For example(some pseudocode):

```
if (square(x, y).id == 1)commandCenters.remove(index);
if (square(x, y).id == 2)turrets.remove(index);
...
```

Is there a way to make this less tedious, or more efficient?

Comment: Are `CommandCenter`'s and `Turrets`'s descendant from a parent building class? If so you could just give each tile a property of `building` and choose that way.

Comment: @scrappedcola CommandCenter and Turret are their own classes. They aren't really linked in anyway.

Comment: It would be easier and more oop if they were. Since they conceivably share some properties and methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have both classes extend from a `Building` base class.

```
class CommandCenter extends Building { }
class Turret extends Building { }
```

Then you can maintain a single list of buildings of all types.

```
List<Building> buildings = new ArrayList<>();
```